# Vue router-link pass prop getting undefined

Tags: vue.js, vue-router

This is how I passed the prop:

```
<router-link :to="{ name: 'Cart', params: { payment_method: 'cod' } }">
```

Router component is like this:

```
{
    path: "/cart",
    name: "Cart",
    component: Cart,
    props: true,
    meta: {
      requiresAuth: true,
    },
},
```

in the receiving route, Props:

```
  props: {
    payment_method: String,
  },
```

I am getting undefined as value for payment_method. what is wrong here?

Answer (score 1):

Change your router component path to:

```
{
    path: "/cart/:payment_method",
    name: "Cart",
    component: Cart,
    props: true,
    meta: {
      requiresAuth: true,
    },
},
```

Comment: This will indeed work, but you will end up with multiple routes to your cart (one per payment method + 1 with no payment method) and this might not be desirable. If it isn't - the options are: (1) use state management to save the selected payment method and read it in the Cart component or (2) use `query` instead of `params`, but this url will end up being `.../cart?payment_method=cod`.

Comment: Tried this after googling. Still getting 'undefined'! With this warning in console
'[vue-router] missing param for named route "Cart": Expected "payment_method" to be defined'

Comment: I haven't worked with the route 'meta' property, but I would try commenting out your meta property and see if it works. If so, then troubleshoot from there.

Answer (score 1):

Try to set **payment_method** as **slug** in route with `props:true` and catch the route's prop directly in data of vue instance

```
<router-link :to="{ name: 'Cart', params: { payment_method: 'cod' } }">
```

```
{
    path: "/cart/:payment_method",
    name: "Cart",
    component: Cart,
    props: true,
    meta: {
      requiresAuth: true,
    },
},
```

catch directly in data

```
data: function () {
    return {  
      payment_method: this.$route.params.payment_method, 
    };
  },
```

This will resolve your problem